# Tuckey UrlRewrite Filter redirecting all http requests except foo.html

Tags: tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I'm trying to redirect all http requests to https except "health.html" which I need to serve over standard http on port 80; For some reason the rules below don't seem to be doing it - I'm sure it's a syntax thing...

Thoughts?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!DOCTYPE urlrewrite PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite      4.0//EN" "http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite4.0.dtd">
<urlrewrite>

<rule match-type="regex">
    <note>
        Redirect all http requests to https except health.html for EB monitoring
    </note>
    <condition type="header" operator="equal" name="X-Forwarded-Proto">^HTTP$</condition>
    <condition name="request-uri" operator="notequal">^/health.html(.*)$</condition>
    <from>^.*$</from>
    <to type="permanent-redirect" last="true">https://%{server-name}%{request-uri}</to>
</rule>

<rule>
  <note>
    Allow TomCat to have SES links.
  </note> 
  <condition type="request-uri" operator="notequal">\.(bmp|gif|jpe?g|png|css|js|txt|pdf|doc|xls|cfc|ico|php|asp)$</condition> 
  <condition type="request-uri" operator="notequal">^/railo-context(.*)$</condition>
  <condition type="request-uri" operator="notequal">^/flex2gateway(.*)$</condition>
  <condition type="request-uri" operator="notequal">^/jrunscripts(.*)$</condition>
  <condition type="request-uri" operator="notequal">^/cfide(.*)$</condition>
  <condition type="request-uri" operator="notequal">^/cfformgateway(.*)$</condition>
  <condition type="request-uri" operator="notequal">^/files(.*)$</condition>
  <condition type="request-uri" operator="notequal">^/images(.*)$</condition>
  <condition type="request-uri" operator="notequal">^/javascripts(.*)$</condition>
  <condition type="request-uri" operator="notequal">^/miscellaneous(.*)$</condition>
  <condition type="request-uri" operator="notequal">^/stylesheets(.*)$</condition>
  <condition type="request-uri" operator="notequal">^/favicon.ico(.*)$</condition>
  <condition type="request-uri" operator="notequal">^/robots.txt(.*)$</condition>
  <condition type="request-uri" operator="notequal">^/sitemap.xml(.*)$</condition>
  <condition type="request-uri" operator="notequal">^/rewrite.cfm(.*)$</condition>
  <condition type="request-uri" operator="notequal">^/health.html(.*)$</condition>
  <condition type="request-uri" operator="notequal">^/public(.*)$</condition> 
  <from>^/(.*)$</from>
  <to type="passthrough" last="true">/rewrite.cfm/$1</to>
</rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm an idiot.

```
<condition name="request-uri" operator="notequal">
```

should be

```
<condition type="request-uri" operator="notequal">
```

Sigh.